# How to create selector with multiple argument in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Hello it may be silly question but i want to know how to create selector with multiple argument like in Objective C

for example:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action: @selector(buttonTapped:data:), forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal]
```

i am not able to create this kind of selector in Swift can anybody out there to help me in this.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: pass array of object into selector, for multiple argument

Comment: can you give me example code how to do it because i am new to swift programming

Comment: i am passing the selector this way is that right?fetcher.fetchDataWithRequest(request, delegate: self, didFinishSelector: Selector("requestFinish(OAServiceTicket,NSData)"), didFailSelector: Selector("requestTokenResultdidFinish"))

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Selector("buttonTapped:data")
```