# Multiple Parameters/Arguments for Action - Swift

Tags: swift, parameters, action, selector

I found a question most similar to mine however it was not thoroughly answered. It would be great if anyone could help me out. The place where I found the similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375444/how-to-create-selector-with-multiple-argument-in-swift).

I understand clearly how `func test()` would be `"test"` and `test(object:AnyObject)` would be `"test:"`. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift).

So how about 2 parameters? Can swift not do 2 arguments for 'action:'?

```
func popoverSelectedCode (code:AnyObject, desc:AnyObject)
```

I tried testing it out in few different ways below, but to no avail:

```
action: "popoverSelectedCode:,"

action: "popoverSelectedCode:,:"

action: "popoverSelectedCode: :"

action: "popoverSelectedCode: , :"
```

Am only about a week's old in Swift so please be kind.

**EDITED**
Here is a short clip of the code

```
@IBAction func securityQuestButtonClicked (sender:AnyObject)
{
    cellButton = sender as? UIButton;

    var comboDescListArray = TableRoutine.loadCombobox("MobileQuestion")

    var codeObject : NSArray = comboDescListArray[0] as NSArray;
    var descObject : NSArray = comboDescListArray[1] as NSArray;

    var selectionTVC = CPSelectionTVC(style:UITableViewStyle.Plain, codeArray:codeObject, descArray:descObject, target:self, action: "popoverSelectedCode::", widthForViewInPopover:650)

    let navCtl = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:selectionTVC)
    popoverController = UIPopoverController.init(contentViewController:navCtl)

    var contentHeight : CGFloat = CGFloat (UInt(selectionTVC.navigationTitleHeight) + UInt(selectionTVC.rowCount()) * UInt(selectionTVC.cellHeight))

    popoverController?.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(400.0, contentHeight)
    popoverController?.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.bounds, inView:sender as UIView, permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, animated:true)
}
```

The popover appears however upon selecting, it just hangs.

Comment: Did you get an answer ? i am dealing with the same problem. If so how did you write your selector with multiple parameters, and how does the action function looks like. thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was busy with other things, but I spent the whole day today trying to search for new answers. Do keep me posted if you happen to come across an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a note on Swift 2.2.
You can now type the selector as

```
#selector(popoverSelectedCode(_:desc:)
```

Comment: TY! still getting used to new selector. Just In case it helps anyone else I was able to use selector to call a delegate method like so in Swift 2.2
          `textField.delegate?.performSelector(#selector(textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)))`

Answer (score 2):

check this below code

```
func switchCard(card: Int, withCard card1: Int) {
    print(card)
}
let singleTap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "switchCard:withCard:")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 2.2** you can do something like this.

```
myUISlider.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.onSliderValChanged(_:withEvent:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

func onSliderValChanged(slider: UISlider, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    }
```

I hope it helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

With two parameters it becomes `action::`. One colon for one argument.

Comment: Could you elaborate or perhaps give an example?

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate. You supplied popoverSelectedCode function as action for some target. In swift you can turn it a selector like this. "popoverSelectedCode::". Two colon says this action takes two parameters. All this inspecting/resolving performed in runtime by the objective-c runtime

Comment: I tried as you have suggested but unfortunately it still does not pass into the action function at all.

Comment: What is the source of this action ?

Answer (score 1):

If the function has two parameters like below.

```
func clicked(sender:AnyObject,value:AnyObject)
{
}
```

Then

```
action = "clicked::"
```

Comment: hi rakeshbs, yeap! I tried that as shown in my edited part. But problem is, the popover wont move. It just hangs there in the selected state.

Comment: I have pasted the entire function as you requested. I did not see the need to paste the action function as its not even passing through.

Comment: var selectionTVC = CPSelectionTVC(style:UITableViewStyle.Plain, codeArray:codeObject, descArray:descObject, target:self, action: "popoverSelectedCode::", widthForViewInPopover:650)

Comment: is `CPSelectionTVC` a `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can achieve it in your case:

```
action: "popoverSelectedCode:desc:"
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple arguments passes in selector method:

```
let swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(ImageViewController.handleTap(_: sender :)))
myCell.imageViewPhoto .addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
```